# How to solve javascript mocha testing Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, es6-modules

I tried to run testing using supertest and mocha but I got an error when run command mocha ./test/*

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at new Script (vm.js:88:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:261:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:309:10)
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:195:29)
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:145:37)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:182:24)
```